# Unable to switch to 'Remote Branch' - Head Detached

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Unable to switch to 'Remote Branch' - Head Detached

Output from GitBash (Listed below; the remote branches are listed, being two in total: Master and Trunk):

```
  [Laptop1 ~/Desktop/User1 (master)]$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/master/master
  remotes/master/trunk
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/trunk
[Laptop1 ~/Desktop/User1 (master)]$ git checkout remotes/master/master
Note: checking out 'remotes/master/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 57df590... Third coommit...
[Laptop1 ~/Desktop/User1 ((57df590...))]$ git branch -a
* (HEAD detached at master/master)
  master
  remotes/master/master
  remotes/master/trunk
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/trunk
[Laptop1 ~/Desktop/User1 ((57df590...))]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The info message says it all: Invoke `git checkout -b remote-master remotes/master/master`. This creates the new branch `remote-master` from `remotes/master/master`. To let your local `remote-master` branch track the remote branch, invoke `git checkout` with the `--track` option.

To see which remote branch your local branches track, invoke `git branch -v`.

You should probably read an intro to git (such as https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) to get you started with git.

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry im new to Git, why would i need to create a new branch 'remote-master' if the i have a *master local branch and the remote branch 'remotes/master/master' already exists?

Comment: You aren't allowed to "check out" remote branches. Remote branches track where the remote was when you last talked to it, you're not allowed to modify such a branch other than by fetch/push/pull or similar. The only way to check out a remote branch is to create a local branch from it.